# Google maps for Expression Engine issue

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, low

[image]I have a channel set up that has acc_longitude and acc_latitude, these fields have the correct coordinates for the destination applied. I am using this code below to try and display a map with the a marker of the destination. Below you can see my code for my attempt at this, I am just receiving a white box with no map in it. Any ideas? js script running below looks like this (being pulled in by the add-on).

{exp:gmap:init id="map" class="gmap" latitude="{acc_latitude}" longitude="{acc_longitude}" style="width:100%;height:200px;"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that the jquery.min.js file was in the footer, it was preventing the map from being rendered